# Show JSP source as a HTML

Tags: java, html

I'm having some jsp pages that I would like to show there source as an html page like in the example webapp that is provided with tomcat.
I have tried few online java2html converters but couldn't obtain source
as in tomcat example. 
Could someone tell me what they have used?

Comment: What webserver are you using?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how this is relate to server. I just want to generate html page from jsp source.

Comment: Different servers use different configurations.  You have to deploy a web app to them sometimes differently

Comment: i didn't understand the question .jsp is a server language if you view jsp page on web browser you can see html codes

Comment: Read every line from JSP and display it as html formatted content.

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond This is not related to any deployment process

Comment: @FastSnail I have a jsp page. I want to show the source of that jsp (not compile execute jsp) when user click some button. e.g/ in the example tomcat webapp for each example there is view source option

Comment: @Satya I don't want to do this by code. I just want to use an existing tool to get generate the html. I found few but most of them generate complex embedded css styles.

Comment: You could create a small servlet that reads the JSP and then returns the output to the caller. Let me know if you need further guidance on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite few online converters But I found that https://www.palfrader.org/code/code2html/
is pretty organized and it is easily add few lines of code to the generated html file rather than regenerating